# JSON object parsing error in Jquery

Tags: jquery, json

```
[
    {
        "regNo": "1",
        "regDate": "2025-05-12",
        "patientName": "Ratna",
        "address": "saasgasgasga",
        "city": "Hyderabad",
        "phno": "2147483647",
        "mrgStatus": "single"
    }
]
```

this comes from server to client i'm using `jQuery.parseJSON()`method to parse the data but it doesn't work.. can any one help me how to parse it...???

my code is like this..

```
success:function(data)
{ 
 var myObject = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
 $("#patname").val(myObject.patientName);
 $("#guaname").val(myObject.fathername);
 $("#age").val(myObject.age);
 $("#addr").val(myObject.address);
}
```

but this displays empty...

Comment: Did you know that you only have to write `jQuery` in its long form once? By wrapping your code in `(function($) { .... })(jQuery);`, you can use `$` no matter if `noConflict` has been used or not.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It already has been converted from JSON to an object - you don't need to parse it again.

```
success:function(data) { 
    $("#patname").val(data[0].patientName);
    $("#guaname").val(data[0].fathername);
    $("#age").val(data[0].age);
    $("#addr").val(data[0].address);
}
```

Comment: "It already is JSON formatted" --- well, it depends, but in this case most likely it is

Comment: True, I supposed I should say it's already been converted from JSON to an object.

Comment: if i use $("#patname").val(data[0].patientName); it will print NULL

Comment: If you put the following in your `success` handler, what do you see in the console: `console.log(data[0]);` ?

Comment: if i use $("#guaname").val(data[0]); it will print " [ "

Comment: Have you set `dataType: "json"` in your `$.ajax()` settings?

Comment: in console it will displaying " [ "

Comment: Ya now i set dataType: "json" to $.ajax() its working fine
thank You Rory McCrossan

Answer (score 0):

```
    success: function(data) {
     // here data is an array, so you need data[0] to get the object
     $("#patname").val(data[0].patientName);
     $("#guaname").val(data[0].fathername);
     $("#age").val(data[0].age);
     $("#addr").val(data[0].address);
}
```